# Loading Json data to Redshift using Spark results in null values

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using this [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) library where I want to load the data in either Array or Json format shared in this link [querying-json-data-in-amazon-redshift](http://optimalbi.com/blog/2014/04/14/querying-json-data-in-amazon-redshift/).
In Dataframe, I am reading data from Mongodb & I am converting the dataframe to Json & then pushing to Redshift & it is able to load without any errors/Exceptions. But in Redshift,the column values are showing values as NULL.

I am using [spark-mongodb connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) & I want to know,how I can store the Mongodb data in Array or Json format ?? Is it possible to pull Mongodb data & put it in Redshift in either Array or Json format ?